# Add a class on a condition

Tags: typescript, vue.js

I would like to add a specific class on a condition with vue js.

I have 2 values in my DataStore like this (TypeScript):

```
value1: 0 as number,
value2: 0 as number
```

And with this value, in my template, I would like to add the classes:

```
blue--text if value1 == value2
or
red--text if value1 != value2
```

like this:

```
<p class="blue--text">{{ value1 }}</p>
or
<p class="red--text">{{ value1 }}</p>
```

Do someone have any idea how to do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use a simple condition with a ternary and the `:class` directive:

```html
<p :class="value1 === value2 ? 'blue--text' : 'red--text'">{{ value1 }}</p>
```

Only if value1 is equal to value2 the blue class is applied, if not the red one.

Answer (score 2):

To render classes depending on conditions you can pass an object to the class directive. It will render those keys of the object as class names, that have a `true` value.

```
<p 
  :class="{
    'blue--text': value1 == value2,
    'red--text': value1 != value2
  }"
>
    {{ value1 }}
</p>
```

See the documentation: https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/class-and-style.html

Comment: I have an error when I had your code like this : 
<th :class="{
              'blue--text': carTotalsStores === cacTotalsStores
              'red--text': carTotalsStores != cacTotalsStores
            }">{{ carTotalsStores }}</th>


The errors is : unexpected string in

Comment: @AntoineKurka Just put "," between each key-value pair.