# Change Vue Element UI table cell style based on value

Tags: css, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component, element-ui

I use [Element UI](https://element.eleme.io/#/en-US/component/table).
How can I change the color from the `rate` cell value?  If rate < 0 then color is red, else color is green.

Maybe the table attribute `cell-class-name` can help me?

HTML

```html
<el-table
    :data="tableData"
    style="width: 100%">
    <el-table-column
        prop="date"
        label="Date"
        width="180">
    </el-table-column>
    <el-table-column
        prop="name"
        label="Name"
        width="180">
    </el-table-column>
    <el-table-column
        prop="rate"
        label="Rate">
    </el-table-column>
</el-table>
```

JS

```js
export default {
    data() {
        return {
            tableData: [{
                date: '2016-05-03',
                name: 'Tom',
                rate: 1
            }, {
                date: '2016-05-02',
                name: 'Tom',
                rate: -1
            }, {
                date: '2016-05-04',
                name: 'Tom',
                rate: 22
            }, {
                date: '2016-05-01',
                name: 'Tom',
                rate: -22
            }]
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You want css classes based on conditions. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66436357/add-a-class-on-a-condition/66436454#66436454

Comment: @Reynicke He's using a 3rd party library component, so that suggestion isn't possible because it requires access to internal tags

Answer (score 3):

Bind a method to the `cell-class-name` prop of `<el-table>`:

```html
<el-table
  :data="tableData"
  style="width: 100%"
  :cell-class-name="classChecker"
>
```

Define that `classChecker` method to test for the `rate` column and conditionally apply a class to the cell based on the value:

```js
methods: {
  classChecker({ row, column }) {
    if (column.property === 'rate') {
      const val = row[column.property];
      if (val > 0 ) {
        return 'greenClass'
      } else {
        return 'redClass'
      }
    }
  }
}
```

***CSS***

```css
.greenClass {
  background: green;
}
.redClass {
  background: red;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a columnn template

```
<el-table-column prop="rate" label="Rate">
      <template #default="scope">
          <label class="scope.row.rate < 0 ? 'danger' : 'success'">{{scope.row.rate}}</label>
      </template>
 </el-table-column>
```

[Link](https://element-plus.org/#/en-US/component/table#custom-column-template)

Edit:Link